# c++ Boost random ints from multiple ranges using single generator

Tags: c++, boost, random

Using [boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) I'm trying to sample sets of uniformly distributed integers from different ranges, but using the same underlying random number generator. For each range I am defining a different function returning the the random numbers.
However, it seems that each function returns the same number.

An example illustrating the approach:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

struct RandomNumberGenerator {
  boost::mt19937 generator;

  RandomNumberGenerator(long seed) {
    generator.seed(seed);
  }

  boost::function<int()> getRandomFunctionInt(int min, int max) {
    boost::uniform_int<> uni_dist(min, max);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > uni(generator, uni_dist);

    boost::function<int()> f;
    f = boost::bind(uni_dist, generator);
    return f;
  }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  RandomNumberGenerator rng(1729);
  boost::function<int()> runif1 = rng.getRandomFunctionInt(0,  1000);
  boost::function<int()> runif2 = rng.getRandomFunctionInt(0, 10000);

  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::cout << runif1() << ", " << runif2() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The output was:

```
212, 2121
623, 6226
259, 2590
[...]
```

Is there any way to un-correlate the functions? For the sake of reproducibility of my experiment I would like to work with a single seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = boost::bind(uni_dist, generator);
```

You need to pass a reference to the generator. Right now, you're passing a copy of the generator, which means that each `f` object has a copy of the generator in its initial state.

```
f = boost::bind(uni_dist, boost::ref(generator));
```

A different version using Lambdas would make the ambiguity more visible (and easier to detect/resolve):

```
f = [uni_dist, this] {return uni_dist(generator);};
```

Also, c++11 introduced the `<random>` header, which provides all the same functions and more that boost's `random` headers provide, so there's not really any reason to keep using the boost version anymore.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my rookie mistake... answer accepted and appreciated! Switching to the standard `<random>` header is good advice as well.
+1 for the solution using lambda functions - one small catch, though: in C++11 member vars (like `generator`) cannot be captured directly, had to resort to a local variable and capture that one:
`boost::mt19937 &g = generator`

Comment: @mrhd I think member variables can be captured if you capture `this`. I've revised the answer to account for that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, your solution is more concise. I realize now that it was really the boost::bind() that made a copy since you did not need to pass by reference in `uni_dist(generator)`.